# Nix is building ghc during on nix build command (How to fix the cache?)

Tags: nix, install

I'm preparing the Plutus Pioneer program and installing the environment.

After installing `nix` and updating the "IOHK binary cache", I tried to do `nix build` but it seems that it is building and compiling `ghc` as shown below and it takes a very long time.

```
MyMac$ nix build -f default.nix plutus.haskell.packages.plutus-core
trace: To materialize project.plan-nix for Agda entirely, pass a writable path as the `materialized` argument and run the 'updateMaterialized' script in 'passthru'.
[1/1/619 built] building ghc-8.6.5 (buildPhase): clang-7: warning: argument unu
```

Current **nix.conf**

```
substituters        = https://hydra.iohk.io https://iohk.cachix.org https://cache.nixos.org/
trusted-public-keys = hydra.iohk.io:f/Ea+s+dFdN+3Y/G+FDgSq+a5NEWhJGzdjvKNGv0/EQ= iohk.cachix.org-1:DpRUyj7h7V830dp/i6Nti+NEO2/nhblbov/8MW7Rqoo= cache.nixos.org-1:6NCHdD59X431o0gWypbMrAURkbJ16ZPMQFGspcDShjY=

sandbox = true
extra-sandbox-paths = /System/Library/Frameworks /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks /usr/lib /private/tmp /private/var/tmp /usr/bin/env
extra-experimental-features = nix-command
build-users-group = nixbld
```

I found the following warning message:

> If you want to use Nix with this project, make sure to set up the IOHK
> binary cache. If you do not do this, you will end up building GHC,
> which takes several hours. If you find yourself building GHC, STOP and
> fix the cache.

Could you guide me how I can fix the cache?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this on an m1 Mac? Binary cache doesn't have Mac arm binaries.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, please see below spec of mine. (1.1 GHz Intel Core M, MacBook (Retina, 12-inch, Early 2015) it is a little older one. I've remove all nix installation and install again, found something different log as below but still it is trying to building ghc-8.6.5

Comment: MyMac$ nix build -f default.nix docs.site
[1/3/4 built, 134 copied (207.2 MiB), 185.9 MiB DL] building old-ghc-nix: : [1/3/4 built, 134 copied (207.2 MiB), 185.9 MiB DL] building old-ghc-nix: [1/3/4 built, 134 copied (207.2 MiB), 185.9 MiB DL] building old-ghc-nix: trace: To materialize project.plan-nix for Agda entirely, pass a writable path as the `materialized` argument and run the 'updateMaterialized' script in 'passthru'.
[1/109/730 built, 434 copied (1193.3 MiB), 438.4 MiB DL] building ghc-8.6.5
(buildPhase): "inplace/bin/ghc-stage1" -hisuf p_hi -osuf  p_

Comment: I also saw `warning: ignoring untrusted substituter 'https://hydra.iohk.io'` with Nix in multi-user mode. It was fixed by specifying these substituters in `/etc/nix/nix.conf` rather than `~/.config/nix/nix.conf`. It appears Nix reads both of these configuration files, but does not trust the substituters in the latter.

Answer (score 4):

It may be the case that you edited your nix.conf file after you launched nix-daemon.
You would need to kill and start the daemon again to pick up the updated nix.conf:

> $ sudo pkill nix-daemon

and then

> $ sudo nix-daemon &

After that. Your non-root user will use substitutes.

source: https://docs.cachix.org/faq#why-is-nix-not-picking-up-on-any-of-the-pre-built-artifacts

Comment: Welcome to Cardano SE! As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I tried to solve this issue with various way so anyway I could solve this issue. But I'm not sure what make it run. anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: If your systems uses systemd to run services you can restart the daemon using
`sudo systemctrl restart nix-daemon.service`